# Shiny FilesButton start directory

Tags: r, shiny, directory, path

i got a shiny app where the User must select a file to be processed further.
The shinyFilesButton lets me do exactly that - BUT, the file selection always starts at the root directory (in my case C:). Is it possible to let the file selection start at a specific directory? For example, i would like the file selection to start at "C:\Users\admin\Documents"

This would greatly improve usability.

Thank in advance!
Patrick

MWE

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
    

    
    
       
        shinyFilesButton("filePath", "Please Select File", title = "Select File", multiple = FALSE,
                                   buttonType = "default", class = NULL),   
                  
        br(), 
        br(), 
        
        textOutput("inputFile")
        
    
)


# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    volumes = getVolumes()
    observe({
        shinyFileChoose(input, "filePath", roots = volumes, session = session)
        
        if(!is.null(input$filePath)){
            # browser()
            input_file_selected <- parseFilePaths(volumes, input$filePath)
            output$inputFile <- renderText({
                paste("File Path: ", as.character(input_file_selected$datapath))
            })
        }
    })
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the role of the `roots` option:

```
shinyFileChoose(input, "filePath", roots = c(Documents = "C:/Users/admin/Documents"), session = session)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Stéphane, the file selection starts at the selected directory. But the output now only shows "NA" instead of the file path selected?

Comment: Not my brightest moment.... I just had to change the `parseFilePaths(roots = )` to the same roots directory - Thanks again!